# Wanna load another php file when im done with button_submit

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php function my_plugin_settings_page() {?>

    <div class="wrap">
    <h2>Staff Details</h2>

    <form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'my-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'my-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Accountant Name</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="accountant_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('accountant_name') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Accountant Phone Number</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="accountant_phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('accountant_phone') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php submit_button( 'Save Settings', 'primary', 'wpdocs-save-settings' ); 

    if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
        header('Location: wamp\www\wordpress\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\MaximoPlugin\andra.php');
        exit;

    }?>
    </form>
    </div>
```

My question is, can i redirect a user to another php file in wordpress by adding action to the button_submit ?

So it has like two events. Saving and then redirect the user to another page.

Is this possible on a way. BTW im new to php and wordpress so im sorry for the bad code and stuff.

the if statement isent any good i know, but how can i check if the buttons is submitted and then redirect the user to another wordpress page..(another php site.)

Please give me some input for what i can do or should do.

EDIT:

Ok i changed it to a include, but dont get any response.

```
        </table>
    <?php submit_button(); 

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    include('andra.php');
    }

    }?>
```

Comment: is you code not working or are you looking for an alternative approach?

Comment: Im open for everything so just give me alternatives please

Comment: rather then redirect to a php file, why not include/require the contents of the php file on submit?

Answer (score 1):

You can use wp_redirect  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect to redirect the user to another URL. Simply save your data before redirect call.

```
<?php
wp_redirect( $location, $status );
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The questions is not very clear so I will show two solutions, you can pick the one suits you more:

**SOLUTION 1:**

Make another file `handle_my_request.php`

Change the following lines in your code:

```
<?php submit_button( 'Save Settings', 'primary', 'wpdocs-save-settings' ); 

    if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
        include_once("handle_my_request.php");
        exit;

    }?>
```

Now in `handle_my_request.php`, you can easily write the way you want to handle the request. Eg.

```
<?php

$var1 = $_GET['myvar1'];
do_something($var1);

?>
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

You manually need to make another form and post the fields to the other page you want. For this to happen, you can either GET/POST on server side through PHP (using CURL) or you can GET/POST through javascript on client side.

```
<?php function my_plugin_settings_page() {?>

<div class="wrap">
<h2>Staff Details</h2>

<form method="post" action="options.php">
<?php settings_fields( 'my-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
<?php do_settings_sections( 'my-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
<table class="form-table">
    <tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row">Accountant Name</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="accountant_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('accountant_name') ); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row">Accountant Phone Number</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="accountant_phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('accountant_phone') ); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php 
    submit_button( 'Save Settings', 'primary', 'wpdocs-save-settings' ); 
    if (isset($_GET['submit'])) 
    { ?>
    <form name="redirection_form" action="http://anotherwebsite.com" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="accountant_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('accountant_name') ); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="accountant_phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('accountant_phone') ); ?>" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.redirection_form.submit();
    </script>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Needless to say here that you need to change the variables and method and action of the form to match the next page you are redirecting to.

As I said before, the same can be achieved by PHP CURL.

Comment: Hmm the solution number 1 is enough for me, thank you so much. But my page other page still dosent show up. or i dont get redirected to it.

  </table>
  
  <?php submit_button( 'Save Settings', 'primary', 'wpdocs-save-settings' ); 

  if (isset($_GET['submit'])) 
        include_once("andra.php");
        exit;

  }?>
 </form>

and andra.php is

<?php

echo "asdasdsadasd"; 

?>

Comment: Maybe its a styling issue. Can you check the source html? Right-click on browser and `View Page Source`. There is no reason why it should not show, other than the path. Make sure that the execution file path and `andra.php` are in the same directory, otherwise give the correct path to the file.

Comment: Yeah the andra.php is in the same directory. Do u got it worked in a site ?

Comment: The log seems to be fine, **Wed Jan 28 08:13:55.645630 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5936:tid 312] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.** latest error. But i think many of them are the start restart errors.

Comment: i //var_dump(include_once 'andra.php'); before the if (isset($_GET['submit'])) and the andra.php gets dumped in my main page. So the page works but why dosent it send me to the page and hide my main page.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
    <input type='hidden' name='option_page' value='my-plugin-settings-group'   /><input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" /><input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="fc1447e3e7" /><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/wordpress/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-plugin-settings&amp;settings-updated=true" />              <table class="form-table">
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Accountant Name</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="accountant_name" value="1" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Accountant Phone Number</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="accountant_phone" value="1" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="wpdocs-save-settings" id="wpdocs-save-settings" class="button button-primary" value="Save Settings"  /></p>
```

This is the source view. And yes the andra.php is in same directory.

Im making a plugin for Wordpress, do it have something to do with that ?